# Check if variables are not empty strings in bash with a reverse case switch statement

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I have a number of variables and for each one I need to do the following:
If the variable is `""`, do nothing
If the variable isn't `""`, then `echo "text $var"`.

Each variable will need to send different piece of text.

The way I would like to do this would be with `case` statements.
Normally they work like this:

```
case $var in
  a)
    echo "a"
  ;;
  *)
  ;;
esac
```

However, I would like it to work like this:

```
case !"" in

  $var1)
    echo "var1"
    ;;&
  $var2)
    echo "var2"
    ;;&
esac
```

If the expression is `""` or something like `"1"` then it can be compared with the variables successfully. But it doesn't accept `!""` or other variations of `not ""` that I can think of so it doesn't work.

I could do this with several `if` statements, a function or a `for` loop iterating over the variables. But I can't see a way to do it with only `case`.

Comment: `Each variable will need to send different piece of text.` Could you expand on that? What different text? `If the expression is "" or something like "1" then it can be compared with the variables successfully` Why are you comparing anything with all variables? You state that you want to compare one each variable with `""`, not `""` with all variables. `to do it with only case` Please create an example: given an example set of variables and input conditions, what output do you want to get? Why do you _want_ to "do it" only with case? How would you do it with `if` and `for`?

Comment: bash `case` is supposed to do equal comparison, it can't do not equal. Also it will ends the block when it found first equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an [alternate value expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02): `${var1:+x}` will expand to "x" if the variable is set to a non-empty value, and "" otherwise. So something like this should work.

```
case "x" in
        ${var1:+x}) echo "$var1" ;;&
        ${var2:+x}) echo "$var2" ;;&
        ${var3:+x}) echo "$var3" ;;&
esac
```

But I'd consider this an ugly hack, and prefer a function or something similar as a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you for responding, this does exactly what I was thinking of with case statements.
I have one question about how it works though.
From what I understand
`${var1+x}` adds `x` to the end of `var1` regardless of what it is
and
`${var2:+x}` adds `x` to the end of `var2` only if `var2` is not empty, but why?

and then because of the `:` you only look at the added x and compare that to `x` to decide whether or not to match the case.

Comment: `${var1+x}` and `${var1:+x}` don't add something to the variable, they use the alternate value (`x` in this case) *instead of* the variable's value. See [the POSIX standard on parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), especially the "Use Alternative Value" line and the table just below it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude certain values from the `case` by using `not`. Instead, match on those that shouldn't result in any action too, and, do nothing if you get a match.

In this example, `""` and `"#"` will result in doing nothing. I've used `;&` to let `""` fallthrough to `"#"` just to be able to log that it's doing nothing for both of them.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

var=$1
var1=a
var2=b

case $var in
  "$var1")
    echo "text var1"
    ;;
  "$var2")
    echo "text var2"
    ;;
  "")
    ;&
  "#")
    echo "doing nothing"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "doing the default thing"
    ;;
esac
```